How to make multiple subplots from dictionary
i would like to make subplots using matplotlib for every item in a dictionary.
the following code makes plots for every key and value in the dictionary sequences.
for k, v in sequences.items():
            x = range(0,len(v) - win_size() + 1)
            y = []
            for window in get_windows(v):
                gc_proportion = (window.count("g") + window.count("c")) / len(window)
                y.append(gc_proportion) # y-axis point to plot on graph
            plt.plot(x,y)
            plt.title(k)
            plt.xlabel("nucleotide position")
            plt.ylabel("gc proportion")
            plt.show()

however, rather than the plots being shown one at a time when ran from cmd i would like them to instead show as a group of subplots, something like plt.subplots(len(sequences), 4) (the length of the dictionary could change, i'd like 4 graphs per row though) but i can't get it working. any help is appreciated

You can use the fact that a plt.subplot() call return a Matplolib Axes object which can then be manipulated to set the subplot-specific titles etc.
The math.ceil(len(sequences)/4) bit makes sure that there are enough rows for all the plots. The next argument in the same function call sets the number of columns to 4. We then place the plots anticlockwise on the grid by using the index id (which starts from 1 not 0).
tight_layout() adjusts the titles etc so that they don't overlap.
Call plt.show() outside of the loop so that the plot is only shown once all the sublots have been placed.
The below should solve the problem.
import math

id = 1
for k, v in sequences.items():
            x = range(0,len(v) - win_size() + 1)
            y = []
            for window in get_windows(v):
                gc_proportion = (window.count("g") + window.count("c")) / len(window)
                y.append(gc_proportion) # y-axis point to plot on graph
            ax = plt.subplot(math.ceil(len(sequences)/4), 4, id)
            ax.plot(x,y)
            ax.set_title(k)
            ax.set_xlabel("nucleotide position")
            ax.set_ylabel("gc proportion")
            id+=1

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()



thank you, how do i adjust the figsize using subplot()?

You can do that by adding this line: plt.figure(figsize=(width,height)) before plt.show
